# Short story about a prehistoric man discovering either salt, garlic or onions for cooking

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, prehistoric

It takes place in a prehistoric era. The man is sick to death of the meat he's been eating and he discovers that adding something (onions, garlic, or salt - I can't remember) makes it appetizing again. He compares the meat which "fills the stomach but not the mouth" and the additive which "fills the mouth but not the stomach'.

I read it in a sci-fi anthology probably in the 60s or 70s. It was a fantasy, tonally like Clan of the Cave Bear

Comment: "Prehistoric fiction" is considered to be off-topic, hence the close votes; https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13383/20774

Comment: "is considered" is a bit strong for describing a pretty finely balanced meta post...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is *[The First](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56038)* by Anthony Boucher.

> Sko’s stomach was full but his mouth still felt empty. There had once
> been a time when his stomach was empty and his mouth felt too full. He
> tried to remember. And then, as his tongue touched around his mouth
> trying for that feeling, the thought came.
>
> ...
>
> He pulled the hard purple-brown skin off one yellow-white section and
> smelled it. Even the smell filled the mouth a little. He blew hard
> on the coals, and when the fire rose and the stewpot began to
> bubble, he dropped the section in with the sheep-meat. If one
> fills the stomach and not the mouth, the other the mouth and
> not the stomach, perhaps together ...

Comment: YES! It is indeed "The First" Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: Funny thing about the editor of the *Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction* in 1952, when this work of mundane prehistorical fiction was published. Wouldn't you know it, he was one William Anthony Parker White, alias Anthony Boucher.

Comment: It was fairly common for editors to pen a story to fill both their magazine and their pocket. They were sometimes called pot boilers...

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd - Sko like this strategy!

Comment: And "boucher" in French means "to fill", as in "to fill a hole".